# Is there anything that {worksheet}.Cells.Clear will not remove?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm editing an old excel macro and I was wondering if I could replace

```
       ws.Range("A:M").ClearContents
       ws.Range("F:F").FormatConditions.Delete

       ws.Range("F:F").Interior.Pattern = xlNone
       ws.Range("F:F").Interior.TintAndShade = 0
       ws.Range("F:F").Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
```

with

```
       ws.Cells.Clear
```

Comment: `Is there anything that {worksheet}.Cells.Clear will not remove?` Yes. It cannot delete `Shapes` like button/Charts etc. But then I believe this actually is not your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with this method, but it will clean the entire worksheet and not only the columns specified.